# CSS transition 0s (zero seconds) not working?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to avoid some of the transition effects on the element (for example: `opacity`). I should use `opacity 0s`, because this should be the default value or in other words transition will have no effect on this. But it's not working this way. This is what I tried:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s, opacity 0s;
    transition: all 2s, opacity 0s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s, opacity 0.1s;
    transition: all 2s, opacity 0.1s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

However, if `0s` of the `opacity` changed to `0.1s`, it will work(with duration of 0.1s), is there a way to "disable" the animation in some other way, perhaps, so it will work without even a small value as 0.1s?

Comment: Thank  you Juhana(I forgot a nickname) for adding a snippet. I followed the trick and did the same to another code, just to show the difference of `0s` and `0.1s`

Comment: Using `all` as your `transition-property` isn't very efficient; whenever possible you should use the actual property/ies you want to transition. In the case of your example above, that would simply be `width`.

Comment: Very interesting question @cathe and weird behavior because the spec says this -*If a property is specified multiple times in the value of ‘transition-property’ (either on its own, via a shorthand that contains it, or via the ‘all’ value), then the transition that starts uses the duration, delay, and timing function at the index corresponding to the last item in the value of ‘transition-property’ that calls for animating that property.*. Have you tested this in multiple browsers? Is the behavior same?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an solution for this

`transition: all 2s, opacity 1ms;`

As `0s` is not valid time for this (I don't know why this). and `1ms` is very small time likely to `0s` for human eye.

And for your current problem you can also use `transition: width 2s` which is only applicable for `width`.